# Selenium Chrome webdriver unexpected error (33)

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I've been facing this "unexpected error (33)" when running a script on Excel Vba. There's shouldn't be any issue with the code since it has been running smoothly before this.

I've updated the chrome webdriver and the google chrome to the latest version but the issue still remains.....
Google Chrome Version 115.0.5790.171 (Official Build) (64-bit)
ChromeDriver Version 115.0.5790.170
Is there any other possibilities that I've overlooked?

Comment: Have you updated chrome?

Comment: Try this: 1. Update chrome. 2. Remove old chromedriver file and download new chromedriver. If it doesn’t work then download second last released chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the version of Chrome on my Mac to 115.0.5790.170, and it worked for me. Only this version supports testing 115.0.5790.170